# Django Test (StaticLiveServerTestCase) returns 404

Tags: python, django, angular, selenium, testing

I have a project which uses Angular and Django and I am experiencing a weird behavior when I test my application using StaticLiveServerTestCase and Selenium.

When I start testing it everything seems to work but, if I refresh the main page I receive a 404. So, if I test without base URL it works, but once Angular adds the base URL the test returns 404:
    **http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/development/test**

Base URL defined in Angular at index.html:

My URL is defined as follows:
    **re_path('test', views.index, name='index')**

So, summarizing, when I test http://127.0.0.1:8000/test it works, but if I test http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/development/test it does not -if I run my app normally, both URLs work.

According to my novice knowledge and as the URL pattern is defined both URLs should work. Obviously, I am missing something else.

Thanks in advance.

Note: Test class if defined as follows:

```
class Tests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

def set_chrome_options(cls):
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    return options

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.host = "127.0.0.1"
    cls.port = 8000
    super(Tests, cls).setUpClass()
    cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.DRIVER_PATH, options=cls.set_chrome_options(cls))
    ...
```

Regarding the urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    re_path('test', views.index, name='index'),
    path('project', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
```

Comment: Show us your urls.py. There needs to be a path for /baseURL/test as well as /test. What is baseURL?

Comment: I have tried to add more details to my question, I am sorry I cannot share all details since it is a private project.

Comment: You should show the full trace of the 404. That would help see which patterns were tried. Normally with this `re_path` any url containing “test” anywhere should match and return the index view.

Comment: That's part of the problem, there is no trace... not even django/core/handlers/base.py gets called.
I just get a sad: "Not Found The requested URL /project/development/test was not found on this server."